# I am trying to use photobooth.js on a webpage. It works in JsFiddle, but not locally. What do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The link to the JSfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dyx9jsxa/

I am just trying to run the same thing locally as this example shows, but it seems that photobooth.js is never loading. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code in our HTML file locally:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>




      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


          <script type='text/javascript' src="http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/photobooth_min.js"></script>


      <style type='text/css'>
        #photo {
        height: 300px;
        width: 380px;
    }
    #gallery {
        margin: 5px 0;
        background: #f6f6f6;
    }
      </style>



    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var file = null;
        $('#photo').photobooth().on("image", function (event, dataUrl) {
            file = dataURLtoBlob(dataUrl);
            var size = file.size;
            alert("Picture size: " + size);
            uploadImage(file);
            $("#gallery").append('<img src="' + dataUrl + '" >');
        });
    });

 // (Commented out due to not having this file) 
 //    $(function() {
 //           var coords = $('.photobooth.T').faceDetection();
 //           console.log(coords);    
 //       });


    function dataURLtoBlob(dataUrl) {
        // Decode the dataURL    
        var binary = atob(dataUrl.split(',')[1]);

        // Create 8-bit unsigned array
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        }

        // Return our Blob object
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
            type: 'image/png'
        });
    }

    function uploadImage(file) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        // Append our Canvas image file to the form data
        fd.append("files", file);
        fd.append("album", $("#album").val());
        fd.append("albumkey", $("#albumkey").val());
        // And send it
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://lambda-face-recognition.p.mashape.com/recognize",
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", $("#mashapeKey").val());
            }
        }).done(function (result) {
            alert("Received response..");
            var resultObject = JSON.stringify(result);
            alert(resultObject);
        });
    }
    });//]]>  

    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="photo"></div>
    <h3>Sample Code for Face Recognition in Javascript (Mashape)</h3>
    <h4>Tutorial link <a target="_blank" href="http://blog.mashape.com/post/45712257463/face-recognition-using-javascript-and-mashape">here</a>.  Look at the top, the app is requesting access to your webcam.</h4>  
    1. Mashape key: 
    <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="mashapeKey" value="wEaHZBmxkZsQAcXjyPd8koe1vWzqgkjC" />
    <br/>2. album: 
    <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="album" value="apitraveler" />
    <br/>3.albumkey: 
    <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="albumkey" value="c2de7705a8dfd6056fe0cfb9e486e55ca62bde9ba41fd5990f0d0d8b87aa193f" />
    <div id="gallery"></div>

    </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors locally? Can you confirm photobooth.js is loading locally by hitting f12 in FF or chrome and examining the network tab? as well as jquery loading?

Comment: We have verified there are no errors locally (just edited code to reflect changes). The webcam still is not loading/working as intended.

Comment: @Jaromanda X Windows 7 and Google Chrome

Comment: works for me - except I don't have a camera on this machine, but no errors

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with

```
src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'
```

add http: before // and you will be sweet

The reason using the so called **"recommended"** method doesn't work for **locall** files is that excluding the protocol in a src/href results in the protocol used to load the containing page to be used for the src/href

Therefore `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js` on a page such as `file:///stuff.html` will be attempted to be fetched using the URL `file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js` - at least that's what chrome attempts to do - I can't see what Firefox is attempting to do, if anything, except to say it isn't even attempting to load jquery-1.9.1.js from anywhere at all

Comment: The fiddle is also throwing a js error. TypeError: $(...).faceDetection is not a function

Comment: Yes, we just noticed these errors and fixed them both. The webcam functionality is still not working however even with the function commented out and jquery linked properly.

Comment: @Jaromanda, this is actually the recommended approach to link static files if the link is not a relative link. https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Protocol

Comment: I think you need to figure out why that function was throwing an error rather than commenting it out. That may very well be preventing it from working properly.

Comment: @tellez ... `file:///` ... think

Comment: @tellez Face detection function just returns the coordinates of a person's face when an image is taken. It has nothing to do with the functionality of the webcam itself.

Comment: I haven't used photobooth but it sounds very cool. Just trying to help with general javascript issues. No idea if there are no errors why it would not be working.

Comment: browsers can behave differently with local pages

Comment: @Jaromanada, this is recommended by google coding standards, to omit the http/https protocol on static files like css, js and images to avoid issues with loading unsecure content on secure pages. If google was so wrong I don't think they would be the company they are.

Comment: Check out the standards when you get a chance. https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Protocol#Protocol

Comment: @tellez I don't care what Google say. it simply won't work if the page loaded like file:///

Comment: I know how it works, and I also know when Google are WRONG

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with photobooth.js
Must include the following files in the following order

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryIntegration.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Photobooth.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Tools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Drag.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ResizeHandle.js"></script>
```

And then define

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $( '#example' ).photobooth().on( "image", function( event, dataUrl ){
            $( "#gallery" ).show().html( '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" >');
        });


        /**
         * Tab boxes
         */
        $( '.tab_container' ).each(function( i, elem ){
            $( elem ).find( ".tabs li" ).click(function(){

                $( elem ).find( ".tabs li.selected" ).removeClass( "selected" );
                $( this ).addClass( "selected" );
                $( elem ).find( ".tab_content" ).hide();
                $( elem ).find( ".tab_content." + $(this).attr( "calls" ) ).show();
            });
        });

        /**
         * Link highlighting
         */
        $( "a" ).click(function(){
            $( "#nav a.selected" ).removeClass( "selected" );
            $( "#nav a[href=" + $(this).attr( "href" ) + "]" ).addClass( "selected" );
        });

    </script>
```